# Performing a simple seach using where() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to perform a search that uses checkboxes to look up results in my model, then displays them on the page.

My routes:

```
Route::get('parts/cpu', 'PartsController@cpuList');
Route::get('parts/cpu/search', 'PartsController@searchCpu');
```

My controllers:

```
public function cpuList (){
    $processors = Processor::all();

    return view('parts.cpuList', compact('processors'));
}
public function searchCpu(Request $request){
    $processors = Processor::query();
    $processors->where('tech', '=', $request->input('tech'))->get();

    return view('parts.cpuList', compact('processors'));
}
```

My view:

```
<form method="GET" action="/parts/cpu/search">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="Intel">Intel</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="AMD">AMD</label>
                </div>
                <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-primary">
            </form>
       <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach ($processors as $processor)
                <li class="list-group-item clearfix"><a href="/parts/cpu/{{$processor->id}}">{{$processor->name}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

Im getting the following error: No query results for model [App\Processor].

This is the url being displayed on search: /parts/cpu/search?tech=Intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a routing issue...

if I change the route and the form action to parts/search and /parts/search respectively then it works, it looks like Laravel has a some routes priority that's causing a conflict.

Or it could be interfering with my wildcard route that i have set up for the interior processor details page:

```
Route::get('parts/cpu/{processor}', 'PartsController@cpuShow');
```

If anybody can shed any more light on on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have 2 queries running in your database.

Change this:

```
$processors = Processor::query();
$processors->where('tech', '=', $request->input('tech'))->get();
```

To this:

```
$processors = Processor::where('tech', '=', $request->input('tech'))->get();
```

Comment: It still gives no query results

Comment: there were not two queries anyway.

Comment: My mistake, there are no 2 queries but he is fetching all unwanted data from processor. @SanzeebAryal

Comment: If you get no results means that either your tech value does not much any of your records or you do something wrong to see `$processors`. try changing your where to this  `where('tech', $request->input('tech'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = Processor::query();
$processors = $query->where('tech', '=', $request->input('tech'))->get();
```